# "Package not accessible" error trying to import SQL Server JDBC package in project

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to use the SQL Server JDBC package in my Java project. I'm getting a `The package com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc is not accessible` error in my import statement. I've already added the MSSQL JDBC driver to the appropriate classpath (see attached image). I have another project set up exactly the same way that works just fine. The driver used is the same and the import statements match. Here are my import statements:

```
package Main;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
```

None of the other import statements throw an error. I am using this driver: `mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar`. I am also using JDK 13 for both projects.

[image]

Comment: That driver [officially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) only supports JDK 8, 11 and 12. No clue why it works in one project and not another. Are you absolutely sure they're set up the same way?

Comment: Does your project contain a module-info.java? Given the screenshot contains both a Modulepath and a Classpath, it sounds like you are trying to write modular code, but aren't properly adding the driver on the modulepath.

Comment: My project contains module-info.java. I looked over the projects a second time, and the project that works has all its code in individual class (.java) files, all contained in the default package. The other project doesn't have a default package. I created a package for my code to run in, called it Main, and created a class in that package called clsMain. This is where my code runs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I deleted `module-info.java` and this resolved the error.

Comment: Put a string requires java.sql; in the module-info.java file........ is a better option as mentioned in the next answer.

Answer (score 18):

Put a string `requires java.sql;` in the `module-info.java` file.